# How to pass Columns itself as parameter in PIG scripts

Tags: hadoop, command-line, apache-pig

In my PIG script i want to pass the column position as parameter, please let me know how can i achieve that

```
a = load '$path' using PigStorage('');
b = group a by $CountColPos;
c = foreach b generate group,COUNT(a);
d =  ORDER c by $0;
STORE d  INTO '$TempCountDir';
```

Here how can i pass the value for $CountColPos, using the -p option from comma

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

$ pig -p \$0 script.pig

You need to escape the dollar sign so that the shell doesn't treat it as an environmental variable.